# Client id and secret as part of query parameter

Tags: oauth

In CA SSO client_id and Client_secret are passed as part of query parameter. is it secured to pass as part of query parameters? even though it's https my research on internet says  it's not best practice or safe enough to pass secured information as part of query param.

ex: 
https://api-oidca.example.com/auth/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=test&client_secret=124ddeee-5c08-4bba-b786-2c0d9233d336

Comment: inside TLS, query params are as protected as POST requst body. But, many systems (http client, proxies, load balancers, web servers, app servers, etc.) log query params but don't log bodies. Many systems that do log bodies do not log authorization headers. Auth information should be sent in the http authorization header because many systems know to be careful with that header.

Answer (score 4):

How do you define ‘secure’? It’s certainly not as nice as sending credentials as headers, but Z.T. is right that they can’t be accessed in a URL using TLS. That being said, also as Z.T. alluded to, the fact they’re being sent in a URL means that it’s also likely (or at least much more likely) they’re being logged. Credentials being logged both poses its own set of risks and implies the possibilities of others.

So to answer your question of whether it’s secure to use credentials in URLs - really the answer to that depends on what your threat model looks like. My guess, based on what you’ve described, is that it’s maybe not extremely risky but also maybe not great. (Caveat emptor that that’s just a guess though.)